# Wrapper function around an abstract method

Tags: php, abstract-class

I have an abstract class(abs_job) with an abstract method(run()). This method is implemented in various classes extending the abs_job. Now I am trying to create a wrapper function around run() in abs_job class to add few statistics as how long the run() executed and record the success/failure of run().

Is there any way to achieve this so that all the classes extending abs_job gets to use this wrapper for free. ?

Help appreciated!!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason abstract classes exist is to specify a class that cannot ever be instantiated by itself, but which can dictate all the stuff that has to be defined in any class that extends that abstract class. That being the case, your abstract class, **abs_job**, can define an abstract method that *must* be defined in any class--let's call it **run** -- that extends your abstract class. Then abs_job can define some other method, let's call it **run_wrapper** that can do some other stuff and then call the run function and be absolutely certain that it is defined in the extending class.

Here I write a wrapper function, abs_job::run_wrapper(), that calls the run() method defined in some_class:

```
abstract class abs_job {
    // you must define this function in any class that extends abs_job
    abstract protected function run();

    // this is your wrapper function
    protected function run_wrapper() {

        // do some stuff blah blah

        $this->run(); // this function must be defined in the extending class

        // do some more stuff blah blah

    }
}
```

then in some class that extends it:

```
class some_class extends abs_job {
    // you have to define this function in any class extending abs_job
    protected function run() {
        // blah blah blah
    }
}
```

then if you instantiate some_class, you should be able to call run_wrapper:

```
$v = new some_class();
$v->run_wrapper();
```

EDIT: apologies for lack of clarity. I've edited this post to make it clearer.